# HTML and CSS for Table

Tags: javascript, html, css

Table Issue

[image]

If I used a table Within td tag why it occur the height problem?

Comment: please share your code that you did

Comment: What "height problem"?

Comment: provide some code then only we can help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no height problem there. 
Your first td element is pushing the height of that row. 
Please provide the code for more info

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
height:100%;
```

on the inner table.